# Query stuck in Mariadb 10.1

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When i executing this query(#written in the end of post#) in mariadb 10.1. its taking 100% CPU utilization and not showing any output.

when i ran this query in mysql 5.7. its gave me error

> "ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP
>   BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
>   'DB.istockstatus.meta_value' which is not functionally dependent on
>   columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

So i have ran below query for changing SQL MODE

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

then its working in mysql 5.7.

But its not working in mariadb 10.1.
Anyone faced this issue. please help.

written in the end of post

```
| 19937 | uRw1oPvHmYiKb7 | localhost | uRw1oPvHmYiKb7 | Query   | 52086 | 

Sending data | 
SELECT   WP_posts.ID FROM WP_posts  
LEFT JOIN WP_term_relationships tr ON WP_posts.ID = tr.object_id 
LEFT JOIN WP_term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id 
LEFT JOIN WP_terms tm ON tm.term_id = tt.term_id 
LEFT JOIN WP_term_relationships tr_v ON WP_posts.ID = tr_v.object_id 
LEFT JOIN WP_term_taxonomy tt_v ON ( tt_v.term_taxonomy_id=tr_v.term_taxonomy_id AND tt_v.taxonomy LIKE 'product_visibility' 
AND tt_v.term_taxonomy_id NOT IN ( 7 ) ) 
LEFT JOIN WP_terms tm_v ON tm_v.term_id = tt_v.term_id 
INNER JOIN WP_postmeta istockstatus ON (WP_posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id)  
WHERE 1=1  AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND istockstatus.meta_value <> ''  AND (
      WP_posts.ID NOT IN (
                                    SELECT object_id
                                    FROM WP_term_relationships
                                    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (7)
                            )
    ) 
AND WP_posts.post_type = 'product' 
AND ((WP_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
AND (  ( LOWER( WP_posts.post_title ) REGEXP  '6?(.*)x?(.*)6?(.*)sq')  
OR ( LOWER(WP_posts.post_excerpt) REGEXP '6?(.*)x?(.*)6?(.*)sq')  
OR ( LOWER(WP_posts.post_content) REGEXP '6?(.*)x?(.*)6?(.*)sq')   
OR  (( LOWER(tm.name) REGEXP '6?(.*)x?(.*)6?(.*)sq' OR LOWER(tm.slug) REGEXP '6?(.*)x?(.*)6?(.*)sq') 
AND tt.taxonomy IN ('product_tag'))  )  
GROUP BY WP_posts.ID 
ORDER BY  istockstatus.meta_value ASC, 
(CASE WHEN WP_posts.post_title LIKE '6 x 6 sq%' THEN 1 WHEN WP_posts.post_title LIKE '%6 x 6 sq%' THEN 2 WHEN WP_posts.post_title LIKE '%6%' 
AND WP_posts.post_title LIKE '%6%' AND WP_posts.post_title LIKE '%sq%' THEN 3 
WHEN WP_posts.post_title LIKE '%6%' 
OR WP_posts.post_title LIKE '%6%' 
OR WP_posts.post_title LIKE '%sq%' 
THEN 4 WHEN LOWER(tm.name) LIKE '6 x 6 sq' 
THEN 5 WHEN LOWER(tm.name) LIKE '%6 x 6 sq%' 
THEN 6 WHEN WP_posts.post_content LIKE '%6 x 6 sq%' 
THEN 7 ELSE 8 END) LIMIT 0, 6 |    0.000 |
```

Comment: Post the TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT (your query) for analysis.  If appears to be 'sending data' or 'trying to gather the data'.  The use of leading % in your LIKE requests will be time-consuming.  Have you rebuilt the indexes in your 10.1.nn version since table creation in 10.1.n for EACH of the tables involved?

Comment: Output of query in Mysql 5.7 : WP_posts ID 3590, 3588,3344,3473,3716,3435
also, i have checked indexing.

Comment: Please review this URL for an example of EXPLAIN output that would be helpful, if you could post it from your EXPLAIN SELECT (your query);   rather than your results of the query.  https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/explaining-mysql-queries/  Also, post TEXT results of SHOW WARNINGS; immediately after completion for any additional clues.